# How to add up the values of some attributes in an XML?

Tags: mysql, sql, xquery

I have an XQuery that needs to sum up all the Book copies that are on hand for a specific library Branch. The Branch numbers are 1,2,3 and 4 so a for loop can be used to account for that number. I need to find how many books each Branch (1,2,3, or 4) has in total.

I've already tried using the sum function for XQuery but it isn't adding up the amount of books for each Branch, instead it's just adding up a total of all the books for all Branches, which is 99. So it's saying Branch 1 had 99 books, Branch 2 has 99 books, and so on.

I've already done this in a SQL Query but I need to convert it to an XQuery.

SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(OnHand) as onHand_sum 
from Inventory 
WHERE BranchNum ='$inputBranch'
```

I need help with the "Stock BookCopies=" portion in the code below.

XQuery:

```
<results>
{
for $x in doc("C:\basex\henry\Branch.xml")/dataroot/Branch
let $s := doc("C:\basex\henry\Inventory.xml")/dataroot/Inventory
where $x/BranchNum = $s/BranchNum
return 
<row>
<Branch Number="{$x/data(BranchNum)}" Name="{$x/data(BranchName)}"/>
<Stock Bookcopies="{sum($s/data(OnHand))}"/>
</row>
}
</results>
```

This code sums up all books for all branches and outputs 99 for each branch.

I need something like 27 for Branch 1, 30 for Branch 2, etc.

Branch.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataroot>
  <Branch>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <BranchName>Henry Downtown</BranchName>
    <BranchLocation>16 Riverview</BranchLocation>
    <NumEmployees>10</NumEmployees>
  </Branch>
  <Branch>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <BranchName>Henry On The Hill</BranchName>
    <BranchLocation>1289 Bedford</BranchLocation>
    <NumEmployees>6</NumEmployees>
  </Branch>
  <Branch>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <BranchName>Henry Brentwood</BranchName>
    <BranchLocation>Brentwood Mall</BranchLocation>
    <NumEmployees>15</NumEmployees>
  </Branch>
  <Branch>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <BranchName>Henry Eastshore</BranchName>
    <BranchLocation>Eastshore Mall</BranchLocation>
    <NumEmployees>9</NumEmployees>
  </Branch>
</dataroot>
```

Inventory.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataroot>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0180</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0189</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0200</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0200</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0378</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>079X</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>079X</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>079X</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>0808</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>1351</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>4</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>1351</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>1382</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>138X</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2226</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2226</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2226</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2281</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2766</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2908</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>2908</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>3350</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>3743</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>3906</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>3906</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>5163</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>5790</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>6128</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>4</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>6128</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>6328</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>669X</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>6908</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>7405</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>7443</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>7559</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>8092</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>8720</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9611</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9627</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>5</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9627</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9701</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9701</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>1</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9701</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9701</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9882</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>3</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9883</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>2</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>3</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9883</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>4</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
  <Inventory>
    <BookCode>9931</BookCode>
    <BranchNum>1</BranchNum>
    <OnHand>2</OnHand>
  </Inventory>
</dataroot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `sum($s/data(OnHand)`, `$s` is bound to `doc("C:\basex\henry\Inventory.xml")/dataroot/Inventory`, that is, to the whole Inventory. Try replacing

```
let $s := doc("C:\basex\henry\Inventory.xml")/dataroot/Inventory
where $x/BranchNum = $s/BranchNum
```

by

```
let $s := doc("C:\basex\henry\Inventory.xml")/dataroot/Inventory
[BranchNum =  $x/BranchNum]
```

so the variable is only bound to the selected subset of the inventory.

Incidentally, the argument to `doc()` is supposed to be a URI, not a Windows filename, but I guess your chosen XQuery processor is letting you get away with that, or you wouldn't have got this far.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works